# How URLENCODE be used within HEADER('Location:') command?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a php code i want header command work with URLENCODE

```
header("location:invoice.php?userID=".$userID."&invoiceID=".$invoiceID);
```

the url show like this below and i want when username call from database if in username any special character like "&" with help of URLENCODE in url & into %26 so URL work perfectly.

```
https://domainname.com/invoice.php?userID=Aayaan&Arbab&invoiceID=13314
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header("location: invoice.php?userID=". urlencode($userID)."&invoiceID=".$invoiceID);
```